# NetBeans no me muestra los errores

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-11

De repente NetBeans dejó de mostrarme los errores en el código. Tampoco muestra advertecias ni cuando le pongo el cursor encima a una variable no la resalta ni me muestra si hay más.

No se si alguien sabe como solucionarlo.

Puse una imagen para que vean que le quité todos los ";" al código y además tengo el cursor en una variable y no la resalta ni muestra errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo mismo con Netbeans 12.0
.....................................

Answer (score 2):

Me paso lo mismo al cambiar el tema de netbeans a oscuro, para arreglarlo debes volverte a descargar java. Para ello nos metemos en tools/options/java y en una pestaña no recuerdo cual exactamente te sale una ventana emergente de descargar java, pulsas ahi y ya se arregla[image: java options]

Un saludo

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio y gracias por tomarte las molestias de responder a la pregunta de OP. ¿Podrías investigar cual es la opción exacta y editar la respuesta para inclurirla? Así te quedaría una respuesta de 10.

Comment: Las respuestas deben ser precisas. Si no tienes seguridad en la solución, puedes dejar un comentario con sugerencias.

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente me paso lo mismo  cuando actualizce a Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0

Me sirvio la respuesta de arriba . El inconveniente estaba en un complemento de javac . La solapa en cuestion corresponde a Java Shell . Se despliega una venta emergente que solicita actualizacion de nb-javac.....  Instalas , reinicias el IDE y listo .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que sirva .
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Me paso lo mismo, sin embargo nunca pude resolverlo por medio de Java shell. Lo solucione activando todas las opciones de la pestaña Hints

[image: Solucion]

Comment: Ten en cuenta que no todos pueden ver las imágenes, por lo tanto, explica en la respuesta a qué pestaña y opciones te estás refiriendo. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Estaba trabajando en un proyecto con spring-boot y no me mostraba los errores, lo que paso es que tenia seleccionada la version 17 de Java, y debe ser la 11. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo solucione colocándole el 11 al archivo pom.xlm  en la parte donde dice
<java.version>11<java.version>
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto realmente no responde a la pregunta. Si tienes una pregunta diferente, la puedes formular haciendo clic en [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). También puedes [ofrecer una recompensa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) para atraer más atención a esta pregunta cuando tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/352490)